# Hibernate 6 + attribute of class persisted as String

Tags: java, hibernate-6.x, spring-boot-3

I face an issue with Hibernate 6 (migration to Spring Boot 3). I have a main entity class `BaseEntity` with a `status` attribute of class `CustomStatus`. In hibernate/JPA query, I like to have this syntax `select * from BaseEntity where status = 'ARCHIVED'` or `select * from BaseEntity where status NOT IN ('ARCHIVED', 'CANCELLED')`. That works well with native query, but I like to use JPA to be able to call service.

Compile is fine, but at runtime, I get an error on query execution:

> `Can't compare test expression of type [BasicSqmPathSource(status : CustomStatus)] with element of type [basicType@4(java.lang.String,12)]`.

---

Initially (Hibernate 5 / Spring Boot 2.7), `@Type` referencing a `AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType` / `AbstractTypeDescriptor` was doing job perfectly.

---

**BaseEntity**

```
@Table(name="base_entity")
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @JavaType(CustomStatusJavaType.class)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
    private CustomStatus status;
}
```

**CustomStatus**

```
public class CustomStatus implements Serializable {
    private final String name;

    public CustomStatus (final String name) { this.name = name;}
}
```

**CustomStatusJavaType**

```
public class CustomStatusJavaType extends AbstractClassJavaType<CustomStatus> {

    public static final CustomStatusJavaType INSTANCE = new CustomStatusJavaType ();

    public CustomStatusJavaType () {
        super(CustomStatus.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(CustomStatus value) {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return value.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomStatus fromString(CharSequence str) {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
        return new CustomStatus(str.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public <X> X unwrap(CustomStatus value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return StringJavaType.INSTANCE.unwrap(
                value == null ? null : value.getName(),
                type,
                options
        );
    }

    @Override
    public <X> CustomStatus wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return new CustomStatus (StringJavaType.INSTANCE.wrap( value, options));
    }
}
```

> ### **UPDATE** with AttributeConverter

**CustomStatus**

```
@Converter
public class CustomStatusAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<CustomStatus, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(CustomStatus status) {
        return (null == status? null : status.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public CustomStatus convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        return (s == null || s.isEmpty() ? null : new CustomStatus(s));
    }
}
```

```
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Convert(converter = CustomStatusAttributeConverter.class)
    private CustomStatus status;
}
```

Alas I get same error...It works if i write a native query, but not with JPA query.

Comment: Have you tried using JPA's own mechanism, with `@Converter`, `AttributeConverter` and `@Convert`?

Comment: @RobSpoor I tried with `@Convert`, alas same error. It works only with native query :-(

Comment: Did you try adding the @Enumerated annotation?

Comment: Have you tried with @Enumerated? specifically, @Enumerated(Enumtype.String) ?

Comment: `CustomStatus` is not an enum...it's a class who allows users to create dynamic status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is your query, `select * from BaseEntity where status = 'ARCHIVED'`/`select * from BaseEntity where status NOT IN ('ARCHIVED', 'CANCELLED')`.

To be more exact, hibernate is not expecting `String`s but `CustomStatus` in your query.

If you don't want to use a native query, you could try using placeholders in your query:

```java
@Query("select * from BaseEntity where status = :status")
List<BaseEntity> getBaseEntitiesWithStatus(CustomStatus status);
default List<BaseEntity> getArchivedBaseEntities(){
    return getBaseEntitiesWithStatus(new CustomStatus("ARCHIVED"));
}

@Query("select * from BaseEntity where status NOT IN :disallowed")
List<BaseEntity> getBaseEntitiesWhereStatusNotIn(List<CustomStatus> disallowed);
default List<BaseEntity> getActiveBaseEntities(){
    return getBaseEntitiesWhereStatusNotIn(List.of(
        new CustomStatus("ARCHIVED"),
        new CustomStatus("CANCELLED")
    ));
}
```

You could also try representing your `CustomStatus` differently, e.g. as it's own entity in a `1:N` relation or by embedding it:

```java
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Embedded
    private CustomStatus status;
    //methods
} 
@Embeddable
public class CustomStatus implements Serializable {
    private final String name;

    public CustomStatus (final String name) { this.name = name;}
    //methods
}
```

With this, you could probably make a query like `select * from BaseEntity where status.name = 'ARCHIVED'`

However, that might require making `name` non-`final`.

Comment: Thanks for ideas @dan1st. Indeed issue came from query. 
`@Embedded` / `@Embeddable` failed for a strange reason (I already have an attribute `name` on my `BaseEntity` and it seems to get mix with `CustomStatus.name`). 
But your first point help me to fix my query by `select * from BaseEntity where status = {new my.package.CustomStatus('ARCHIVED')}`

Comment: In case you still want to use `@Embedded`, you can use a different name for the `name` column using the `@Column` annotation or specify a prefix in `@Embedded`.

Comment: Or alternatively, use `@AttributeOverride` in the entity if you don't want to hard-code a column in the embeddable.